# MPMediaPicker bottom part not responding to the clicks

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmediapickercontroller

I am using MPMediaPicker to play music from iPod Library in my app and facing a very strange issue:

The bottom of my media picker sometimes doesn't respond to the clicks,not even the built in tab bar of MPMediaPicker.Also I can't choose some songs at the bottom of the list.This may be very basic but I am unable to get it right now.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by presenting the MPMediaPickerController in a UIPopoverController